# print custom List in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, object, geonames

I have a custom list earthquakes which contains a list of earthquakes. How do I parse this in JavaScript in order to add it to innerHtml and display on the screen. The problem is that I cannot get this to display on the screen in a div. When it parses I get no result because my javascript is wrong and if I try just printing the result i get [Object object]

So the flow goes input from textbox -> web service -> list to javascript

earthquakes class:

```
 public class earthquakes
{
    public string eqid { get; set; }

    public double magnitude { get; set; }

    public double lng { get; set; }

    public string source { get; set; }

    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    public int depth { get; set; }

    public double lat { get; set; }
}
```

dataEarthquakes class

```
public class dataPostalCodes
{
    public List<postalCodes> postalCodes { get; set; }
}
```

WebService:

```
public static dataEarthQuakes getEarthquakes(dataPostalCodes postalCodes)
    {
        double lat = postalCodes.postalCodes[0].lat;
        double lng = postalCodes.postalCodes[0].lng;

        Uri address = new Uri(String.Format(FindEarthquakes, lat, 0, lng, 0));
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string jsonResponse = string.Empty;
        jsonResponse = client.DownloadString(address.AbsoluteUri);
        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dataEarthQuakes>(jsonResponse);

        return results;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
function OnLookupComplete(e) {
    var result = e;
    var weatherData = new Sys.StringBuilder();
    var line;
    for (var property in result.dataPostalCodes) {
        line = String.format("<b>{0}:</b> {1}<br/>",
                         property, result.dataPostalCodes[property]);
        weatherData.append(line);
    }
    $get('divResult').innerHTML = weatherData.toString(); 
}
```

Json string:

```
{"earthquakes":[{"eqid":"2010utc5","magnitude":7.7,"lng":97.1315,"src":"us","datetime":"2010-04-06 20:15:02","depth":31,"lat":2.3602}, {"eqid":"2009kdb2","magnitude":7.6,"lng":92.9226,"src":"us","datetime":"2009-08-10 17:55:39","depth":33.1,"lat":14.0129},{"eqid":"2010zbca","magnitude":7.6,"lng":123.533,"src":"us","datetime":"2010-07-23 20:51:11","depth":576.3,"lat":6.4939},{"eqid":"2010xkbv","magnitude":7.5,"lng":91.9379,"src":"us","datetime":"2010-06-12 17:26:50","depth":35,"lat":7.7477},{"eqid":"c0000rxc","magnitude":7.4,"lng":143.7392,"src":"us","datetime":"2010-12-21 16:19:41","depth":14.9,"lat":26.8656},{"eqid":"2010zbcd","magnitude":7.4,"lng":123.2677,"src":"us","datetime":"2010-07-23 21:15:08","depth":616.7,"lat":6.7489},{"eqid":"2010wbaq","magnitude":7.4,"lng":96.0805,"src":"us","datetime":"2010-05-09 03:59:44","depth":61.4,"lat":3.7284},{"eqid":"2007hvbq","magnitude":7.4,"lng":142.6846,"src":"us","datetime":"2007-09-28 11:38:58","depth":261.3,"lat":21.98},{"eqid":"2010zbbz","magnitude":7.3,"lng":123.4788,"src":"us","datetime":"2010-07-23 20:08:11","depth":604.5,"lat":6.7079},{"eqid":"2007xvam","magnitude":7.3,"lng":126.292,"src":"us","datetime":"2007-01-21 10:27:42","depth":10,"lat":1.2071}]}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? And I've not used the jQuery get() for DOM manipulation but it seems to me that that's incorrect usage. I would change that last line where you add the data to the div to `$('#divResult').html(weatherData.toString(););` (assuming `divResult` is the id of the div you want to add the content to.

Comment: Just curious, could you also provide an example of the JSON response you're parsing?

Comment: Argh - there shouldn't be that `;` after the call to `toString()`. `$('#divResult').html(weatherData.toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I might do:

```
$.get('my-webservice-url', 
    function(data) {
        OnLookupComplete(data['earthquakes']);
    }, 
    'json');

function OnLookupComplete(e) {
    var weatherData = new Sys.StringBuilder();
    for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++) {
        var line;
        for (var property in e[i].dataPostalCodes) {
            line = String.format("<b>{0}:</b> {1}<br/>",
                             property, e[i].dataPostalCodes[property]);
            weatherData.append(line);
        }
    }
    $('#divResult').html(weatherData.toString()); 
}
```

The idea here is that you make your call to your web service and indicate to jQuery that the response expected is JSON (this is useful in case you aren't setting the `content-type` header correctly in the response from the server).

Once the `GET` request completes, jQuery will call your callback function (the anonymous function you can see in the call to `$.get()`. From your JSON example, I see that you expect an object `earthquakes` which is an array of objects of earthquake details.

The function then calls `OnLookupComplete()` with each the earthquakes array.

`OnLookupComplete()` then iterates over each earthquake, builds the right string and appends it to the `StringBuilder`. Finally, once all earthquakes have been dealt with, it appends the complete set of formatted lines to the `div` with the id `divResult`.

Answer (score 1):

As no.good.at.coding said in the comment, if your weatherData object contains the correct data, then it might be as simple as:

```
$('#divResult').html(weatherData.toString());
```

Another option may be to call parseJSON on your json object and then use jquery's each function to iterate through the results:

```
var results = $.parseJSON(e);
$(results).each(function (i, val) {
    $('#divResult').append('<p>' + val.eqid + '<p>'); // can add markup here for magnitude and other properties
});
```

If you aren't sure what your objects are in javascript, [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a great tool for debugging (or you could use the Developer Tools that are built in to Chrome).

You didn't state an exact problem, but hopefully this will help get you on the right track.